# curl request to facebook redirects me to https://facebook.com/common/invalid_request.php

Tags: php, facebook, curl, cookies

This is a part of the code of a function of a class that I did in early 2015. Today it is no longer working. The variables defined in my code, so that is not the problem...

Now that we're clear, let's get to the point:

The Problems:

1. Do not generate cookies
2. In the login page , I get a red sign with "
   security policy " ...
3. I get redirected to
   https://facebook.com/common/invalid_request.php when I 'm logged (
   below I explain as I did for logging )

Poorly made solutions :

1. To generate cookies , all you did was use an extension for Chrome that shows you cookies.txt called cookies in Netscape format and copy the file with the facebook and log in because I did not allow log in with cookies without Log .
2. I could not fix it

   ```
       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.facebook.com/');
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->CONFIG['cookie']);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->CONFIG['useragent']);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.facebook.com');
       curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));
       curl_close($ch);
       unset($ch);


       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php');
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'email='.urlencode($email).'&pass='.urlencode($pass).'&login=Login');
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->CONFIG['cookie']);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->CONFIG['cookie']);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->CONFIG['useragent']);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.facebook.com');
       $page = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));
       file_put_contents(getcwd().'/debug.html', $page);
       preg_match('/<body class="([^<]+)" dir="ltr">/', $page, $web);
       if(file_exists($this->CONFIG['token'])) unlink($this->CONFIG['token']);

       if(preg_match('/home/i', $web[1])) {
           $this->login = true;
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
       curl_close($ch);
   ```

Comment: I fixed up your English and the formatting of your question to help get you an answer. The first item (1.) in both of the numbered lists in your question is confusing. Revise those if possible to make it clearer.

Comment: The editor has StackOverflow, I do not like at all costs... So I use thought how bad this.

Answer (score 1):

You can´t login with CURL, you need to implement a proper login process and you NEVER need the password for this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login

I suggest using the JavaScript SDK for this, it´s very easy to handle. Here are some links to get you started:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: login with the appropriate process is the only way, you can´t automated that. there is no legal and serious use case for this anyway.